# Plotting histogram in Pandas/matplotlib for each hour of the day

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, distribution

I have a timeseries dataset of hourly granularity showing the price return for an asset during each hour of the day for a year.

I am trying to plot a distribution of returns for each hour of the day and thought there may be a way to group the returns by each hour and then to plot a histogram for each hour - so the output of the loop/function/method (i.e. the goal I am aiming to achieve) would be 24 distribution plot showing the distribution of returns for each hour over of the day across the entire time period.

My current dataframe is multi-indexed as `Day`, `Hour` (this may not be correct to accomplish my goal, and I can change it if required).

I am able to use `groupby` to get an hourly average of return over the timeframe (`df.groupby("Hour").mean()`) and thought I could use a similar method to plot my distributions.

Any suggestions of how to accomplish this goal would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example with very simple data (just 9-10 and 10-11 AM for 3 days):

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

arrays = [[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3], [9, 10, 9, 10, 9, 10]]
ind = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(arrays, names=['Day', 'Hour'])
df = pd.DataFrame({'Price': [34, 35, 37, 31, 30, 29]}, index=ind)

for hour, group in df.groupby("Hour"):
    group.plot(kind='hist', bins=10, title=f'{hour}:00 - {hour+1}:00')
    plt.show()
```

[image]

---

Yes, `groupby` already precisely does what you want -- binning a DataFrame into groups.
You can then easily go over those groups and plot each one individually.
(In fact, for me calling `.mean()` on the list of groups is the less intuitive thing to do.). This is the output for printing each groupby group:

```
          Price
Day Hour       
1   9        34
    10       35
2   9        37
    10       31
3   9        30
    10       29

(9,           Price
Day Hour       
1   9        34
2   9        37
3   9        30)
(10,           Price
Day Hour       
1   10       35
2   10       31
3   10       29)
```